# Autofac equivalent of Ninject's Get()

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject, autofac

What would the equivilant to to Ninject's .Get() be in Autofac?

```
  Type handlerType = typeof(IMessageHandler<>);
            Type[] typeArgs = { message.GetType() };
            Type constructed = handlerType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
            var handler = NinjectKernel.Get(constructed);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand, but don't you need `IContainer.Resolve(Type)`?

Comment: I'll post that as answer, but remember that Stackoverflow does not replace googling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
IContainer.Resolve(Type)
```